# Converting a custom object list in simple list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of custom objects. Below is the `data class`:

```
data class ProductsResponse(
        val id:String,
        val ProductType:String
)
```

I have a below list:

`var productList: List<ProductResponse>`

I want the output as:

`var productNameList: List<String>`

I want to get a list which consist of only `ProductType` i.e a `list` of `Strings`

I know using a for loop and copying the `ProductType` string to a new list will do the job. But I wanted to do it in a more shorter way using the power `Kotlin` provides.

How can I convert the above custom object `list` to a `list` of `Strings` in **Kotlin way**?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) function:

```
val productNameList:List<String> = productList.map { it.ProductType }
```

This will map each ProductsResponse to it's ProductType.

Answer (score 12):

```
val productNameList = productList.map { it.ProductType }
```

No need to specify type, it will be inferred

Check [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
val productNameList= productList.groupBy { it.ProductType }.keys
```

This is the exactly what you wanted.